# Set input value with JavaScript - depending on value of different input

Tags: javascript, input

Hey I got this problem I cannot work out by myself. It's html form which passes data to PHP to send mail.

First, I have dropdown list:

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose</option>
    <option id="A" value="one@gmail.com">One</option>
    <option id="B" value="two@gmail.com">Two</option>
</select>
```

This dropdown defines the value of next input:

```
<input type='text' name="to" id="to" value="e-mail"/>

<script>
document.getElementById('dropdown').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('to').value = event.target.value  
    }
</script>
```

At last, I need to define third input from the value of second.

```
<input type='text' name="from" id="from" value="Office manager"/>
```

But this last code doesn't work for me:

```
<script>
var name;
if (document.getElementById('to').value == "one@gmail.com" {
    name = "Martin";
} else {
    name = "Tom";
}
document.getElementById("from").value = name;
</script>
```

How do I proceed?
[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jam7m5ca/)

Comment: should move the last piece of code into the `onchange` listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does if you put it like this

http://jsfiddle.net/170x1xs9/

```
document.getElementById('dropdown').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('to').value = event.target.value

    var name;
    if (document.getElementById('to').value == "one@gmail.com") {
        name = "Martin";
    } else {
        name = "Tom";
    }
    document.getElementById("from").value = name;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Guess I was not focused too much.

Answer (score 1):

1. Syntax Error.

   ```
   if (document.getElementById('to').value == "one@gmail.com" // No ')'
   ```
2. If you use `event` in your function, you should pass it as an argument.

   ```
   document.getElementById('dropdown').onchange = function (event /* <-------- HERE */) {
       document.getElementById('to').value = event.target.value  
   }
   ```

   By not declaring it, you're using `window.event`, which might work in some browsers, but it's bad practise.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solution at: http://jsfiddle.net/jam7m5ca/1/

You forgot to pass the parameter `event`.

```
document.getElementById('dropdown').onchange = function (event) {
    document.getElementById('to').value = event.target.value;
};
```